# Invoking Generic Method with the parameter of IEnumerable<T>

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq, generics

This is the method to be invoked:

```
public static DataTable LinqToDataTable<T>(IEnumerable<T> varlist)
{
   ..
}
```

This is the query:

```
var list = from c in db.Person
           join i in db.Employment on c.ID equals i.personID
           join z in db.aspnet_UsersInCompany on i.ID equals z.EmploymentID
           join k in db.aspnet_Users on z.userID equals k.UserId
           join iy in db.WorkPlace on i.WorkplaceID equals iy.ID
           where i.Date == null && (db.Profile.Any(p => p.personID == c.ID) &&
           db.Employment.Any(y => y.personID == c.ID) && c.companyID == companyID2 && iy.ID == WorkPlaceID2)
           select new
           {
                no     = c.registryNo,
                name   = c.name + " " + c.surname,
                istart = i.EmpStartDate,
                isy    = iy.workplaceName,
                email  = k.UserName,
                IDs    = i.ID,
                IDM    = c.ID,
           };
```

I would like to invoke `LinqToDataTable` method, sending the `list` as an argument. 
I attempted to use `<T>` but it's not applicable.

```
DataTable datatable = Tools.LinqToDataTable<>(list.ToList());
```

Comment: `Tools.LinqToDataTable(list.ToList())` should work or `Tools.LinqToDataTable(list)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Drop the generic parameter entirely:

```
DataTable datatable = Tools.LinqToDataTable(list.ToList());
```

The compiler should infer the generic type from there.  You might even get away with passing list directly (by definition, queries are enumerable).

Comment: `ToList` also not required if immediate execution is not intended